# Rails - How to disable access to localhost:3000/users/sign_in on Devise gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I set on my route.rb like this:

```
devise_scope :user do
  get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new"
end
```

Now I can enter on localhost:3000/login and enter on sign_in.

But if I enter on localhost:3000/users/sign_in still works... How to disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Devise [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes):

> Note that you can skip all sessions routes and define only your own
>   using the skip option as below:

```
  devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions]
  as :user do
    get 'signin' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post 'signin' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    delete 'signout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  end
```

> This way :authenticate_user! and other helpers will be redirecting the
>   user to the proper custom pages you defined.